# How to do a tweet with an android application?

Tags: java, android, exception, twitter, twitter4j

I'm developing an android application. I searching for tutorial that teach how to send a tweet inside an android application. I find [these tutorial.](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application//) I copy all the code and I changed the consumer_key nd the consumer_secret but I have these exception:

OAuthRequestTokenTask(17191):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

If anyone know of other toturial that works and it's better please tell me, I don't want a share button, only I want to tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the sample before putting it into the app you're making?
did it work well there?
if so, your app is probably trying to run multiple requests at the same time , causing this exception.

Comment: so what was the problem , and what was the fix?